# How can I make a control scroll to the top of the screen on focus?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to replicate some of the nice functionality of the To, Cc, and Bcc controls that can be seen when composing a new email in the Mail app on Windows Phone 8.1. Whenever one of the fields receives focus, it is moved to the very top of the screen. This happens so that the popup showing auto-complete suggestions has as much space as possible. How is this accomplished?

I believe this behavior can be hacked together using a ScrollViewer and ScrollViewer.ChangeView(), but I am hoping there is a better, friendlier framework method to do this.